# how to get tomcat session attribute from oracle

Tags: oracle, session, tomcat, oracle-apex, pki

I have a web application made using Oracle Apex that implements the session management itself transparently, and I have implemented two-way SSL configuration in tomcat.

So my basic configuration is following

[image: apex architecture]

- database: oracle 11g
- application server: tomcat 7
- apex 5.1

Now I need to add a token-based authentication so I have added a filter in the "ORDS" (Oracle Rest Data Service) configuration files and added a Java class. Now I have my token attribute added to the tomcat sessions:
[image: this is what I have in my tomcat manager, my token information are added to this session]

But I need to access those attributes from inside my Oracle Database (in Java or PL/SQL) so I can do the authentication with it.

The `Session.getAttribute` doesn't seem to work there because all I have (sent via cookie) from tomcat session is just its `jsessionid`